# what is the Regex for this these cases

Tags: regex, grok

What is the regex for this :

```
word=microsoft-ds_tc

word=%{?}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capture grouping like following after `word=` :

```
word=([a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-Z]{2})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY2cR0/1)

But note that this will match alphabetical characters and in first position any combination with length 1 or more and for 2nd and 3rd parts any combinations with length 2 (`{2}`).

Also based on which language you are using you need to get the first group match,if you use the preceding pattern.

If you dont want to use grouping you can use a positive look behind :

```
(?<=word=)[a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]{2}_[a-zA-Z]{2}
```

If you want to match any combination of alphabetical characters with `-` and `_` you can just use the following :

```
word=([a-zA-Z_-]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nW5dT2/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,it's just an example i mean the word can be:
word=wordddd_rrrrrr
or word=ddddd-ddd or word =ddddd

Comment: @Morito checkout the edit!

Comment: it works thanks :* , but any help for this :( 
CPU=3,11,3
CPU=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
CPU=ADFFA,38252,137280,1744,4416   
I'm a super beginner in regex . thanks a lot Kasra

Comment: @Morito welcome! use `CPU=([1-9a-zA-Z,]+)`

Comment: You are a super genius my friend! thank's :), i think now that that i'm understanding how to do regex ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the content after `word` does not follow a specific pattern, you can simply use

```
/word=([^\n]*)/
```

Comment: You can simply use `/word=(.*)/` , `.` only includes `\n` with `s` modifier..